# How to retrieve object type in Java?

Tags: java, object

I have an abstract class followed by the concrete class, in my code I am trying to create an object of concrete class with type as abstract class. Below sample snippet shows the object creation:

```
A a = new B();
```

Here, `A` is an abstract class and `B` is a concrete class. For my in-memory database I am creating the table on the basis of object type, in this case here it is `A` and fetches the value referring to the table type. It works fine all the cases except where the object is created in above fashion. Since, I couldn’t find the type of object.

I am not suppose to use `instanceof` to make the code generic. Is there any way to retrieve the type of object in Java 8 or any method which might help?

PS:
To add on I am looking for the result as **A.class**; tried using a.getClass() but this gives me the object class which is B.class not the reference class.

Comment: Are you looking for `.class`, or something else?

Comment: yes I am looking object type

Comment: [`a.getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()v) retrieves the [`Class`-object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) representing the class's type.

Comment: a.getclass() will get me B.class not A.class. I am looking for a way to fetch A.class

Comment: There are corresponding methods (e.g. [`isAssignableFrom(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class))) to determine whether types are assignable-compatible.

Comment: Can you please help me with an example ?

Comment: `A.class.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass());` will return `true`. `A.class.isAssignalbeFrom(String.class))` will return `false`.

Comment: What about just using `a.getClass().getSuperClass()` which returns the direct super class of B . *But be aware*: If you have `C extends B` you'll get `B.class` as result. If you need the "root" super class of C C (A.class) you need to recursive get the super class and stop if its `Object`

Comment: If you want the class of `A`, then `A.class` is what you should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object type of `a` in your example is `B`, and you can retrieve it's runtime class object by calling `b.getClass()`.

On the other hand, if you want the runtime class object that represents `A` you can simply use `A.class`; i.e. the class literal for the `A` class.

On the other hand, if you cannot name `A` in your code but you do have its fully qualified name as a string, then you could so something like this:

```
 String className = "com.example.A";
 Class classOfA = Class.forName(className); // and handle the exceptions
```

On the other hand, if you don't know what the name of `A` is ... in any form ... you could conceivably do something like this:

```
 Object a = new B();
 Class<?> clazz = a.getClass().getSuperClass();
 while (clazz != null && (clazz.getModifiers() & Modifier.ABSTRACT) != 0) {
     clazz = clazz.getSuperClass();
 }
```

The above will give you the nearest *abstract* ancestor class of the actual class of `b`.  (Or `null` if there isn't one.)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `a` always is always of type `A` because you defined `a` to be of type `A` in your Code Snippet `A a = new B()`. `a.getClass()` will return `B.class`, because `B` is a child class of `A` and therefore `B` is `A` *plus* B's implementation. `a.isAssignableFrom(B.class)` can possibly return false, whilst `a.isAssignableFrom(A.class)` is guaranteed to always return true.
To conclude, you already know that `a` is of Type `A`, but if you want to know the actual class of the instance you are using, you can use `a.getClass()` which would return `B.class` in your code snippet. To get the [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) of `A` you can simply call `A.class`.
You can also get `A.class` from the instance by calling [getSuperClass()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--) on `a` (`a.getSuperClass()`) which would return `A` for a direct child class of `A`.

Comment: The point of OP is that he doesn't know `a` is of type `A`.

Comment: The only case I can imagine where this could happen is when reading Objects from a file, but then you should consider redesigning the architecture, like storing some kind of identifier for the type (e.g. an `int`, a `byte`, or a `String`) per object.